# DataGridView Tooltip showing, even when form not focused

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tooltip

**Given**: I have a DataGridView list-based application that uses that uses an external Tooltip (default dgv tooltipp is disabled) to display the large content of a specific column on mouseover.

**The problem**:

It always shows the tooltip on mouseover, even, when the form itself is not in focus.

**Scenario**:

- I'm running my application + Firefox at the same time in non fullscreen mode.
- Using my application i get the tooltip I want.
- Then i am switching to the half overlaying Firefox.
- While my application is behind Firefox it keeps showing the tooltip on top of Firefox, while the form itself is behind it.

Scenario #2:

- My application is showing me a tooltip as it is supposed to.
- I decide to delete that Gridview entry by pressing del-button on my keyboard which opens a yes/no-msgbox.
- the tooltip is displaying on top of the msgbox which makes me unable to use the msgbox buttons with my mouse

**The settings**:

[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub gridView_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseEnter
        If e.ColumnIndex = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).Columns.Count - 1 And Not e.RowIndex = -1 Then
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(sender, sender.rows(e.RowIndex).cells(e.ColumnIndex).value.ToString)
        End If
End Sub
```

What do i need to do to fix that annoying bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim isActive As Boolean
    Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        isActive = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
        isActive = False
    End Sub
```

At anypoint of time just check

`isActive` is `true` of `false`, if `true` then `form` is active.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b1d77a1-1fed-4e41-9f7b-c5c639d83c61/how-to-check-if-my-application-window-form-is-active-get-focus?forum=netfxbcl)

Other solution would be to subscribe to `GetForegroundWindow()` and compare return to your `forms handle`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace MyNamespace
    Class GFW
        <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
        End Function

        Public Function IsActive(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
            Dim activeHandle As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
            Return (activeHandle = handle)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace

If MyNamespace.GFW.IsActive(Me.Handle) Then
'do whatever
End If
```

Comment: Looks more like a workaround than a solution to me, but I'll give it a try!

Comment: Post updates in your question with any problems you have on the way.

Comment: Of cause, I will! I've got it working. I'll give the working solution tomorrow if i find some time during work. Thanks for your help, even though i do not think this is the way it is supposed to work.